# HTML 5 Audio Player and Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, html5-audio, web-applications

my question is: Can the HTML5 Audio Player play files from the device. So if the user downloads a audio file from a website and save it on the device can the player read and play this file in offline modus(without internet)? The player is in an WebApp.

thanx 
newone

Comment: is there no one with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Android and iPhone has WebKit based browser and should support [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

You can ask user to open file, and read it as DataURL using File API, described above.

```
<input type="file" id="file" />

<script>
  player = new Audio();

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
           player.src = e.target.result;
           player.play()            
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
</script>

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

"file" input is not supported in iOS. Also, iOS cannot load media files as data URL, only real URL files can be played.